# How can I test a game on Linux within a Windows 10 system?

Tags: windows, games, virtualization, testing

I'm developing a game in Windows 10, and I'm currently working on a Linux port for it. Yes, you read that correctly.

The only problem I have is how to set up Linux in Windows 10 for testing. I know that there is Bash for Windows 10 and that I can make a VM using VMWare and an Ubuntu ISO.

Which one would be easier to set up and test my game in?

Comment: Questions about Windows should be asked on [su].

Comment: You can install the text-mode userland components of Ubuntu by going to the Windows Store and installing Ubuntu; this won't help unless your game runs in text mode. To run Ubuntu Desktop in graphical mode you need a VM; VMware Workstation or Player work well enough to allow VMs to be used for software development, web browsing, and casual web-based gaming. However, if your game uses graphics intensively you will have to install Ubuntu on real hardware.

Answer (score 4):

VirtualBox supports a maximum of 256MB video memory which is in insufficient for your purposes compared to VMware which you have which supports up to 2GB video memory in VMware Workstation 11. VMware Workstation 15 and later supports virtual graphics memory up to 3GB. Even with that if it you are testing a graphics intensive game, you aren't going to get realistic test results unless you install Ubuntu on your computer's hard drive, not as a guest OS in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Grab Virtualbox.  Free, runs on windows, fire up any linux version out there and run within windows.  Its definitely easier and closest to compatibility within a linux environment that you can get to, especially doing any sort of development for it.